# Should I use a text file or a database for a PHP visitor counter?

Tags: php, visitor-statistic

I need to create a visitor counter for my websites and I'm wondering if it is better to store and read the information from a txt file located somewhere in my host or directly from the database.

Using a database would mean that a DB entry will be created for every single visitor that will access the site and honestly I don't think that would be OK.

Comment: Why is db not ok? Think mysql can't handle a few million rows?

Comment: What kind of DB entry you want to store (what columns)?
The best practice is to use NoSQL DB like Redis.

Comment: I suggest DB for your need

Comment: Thanks guys! I will go ahead with DB!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File counter - when just count.
DB counter - when visit tracking, depenences, analysis, aggregation.

Read file is really faster, when file ***is small***. Still, there may be a [***race condition***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) effect, when site is heavy loaded. There is hard to show linked data, if needed. For this needs there is a great solution: *Database Management Systems*.

Database (with good design) allows to avoid race condition. Also it's a better solution for large amount of linked data structures. It's better, when you need to log visits, referers, etc...

**DB Suggestions:** you might store counter in one row of `global_settings` table and update it within each page visit, or you might get it by registrating each visit in `visit` table (with additional data, like `IP`, `DateTime`, `UserID`, etc...) with `SELECT COUNT(*) from visit;`.

There is another related topic ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853482/flat-file-vs-database-speed)***.

Comment: In general I agree with you, but you should extend your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Loading anything from text files is pretty bad practice. Using a database is the better solution. Databases are meant to store large amounts of data, so it is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Loading from text files is not bad practice. I cache many larger database intensive pages into flat text. Right tool for the job

Comment: Caching is a different story; I was referring to the storage of data in a general sense.

Comment: Check out [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853482/flat-file-vs-database-speed).