# Can saving data in SQLite by a few users cause collision as flat file approach can do?

Tags: sql, sqlite, flat-file

According to [stackoverflow.com/a/6853534](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6853534)

> A text file doesn't support writing by multiple users (what if two
> people are posting to the same room at the same time?), and can easily
> become corrupt.
>
> All things considered, I'd say it's better across the board to use a
> DB, even if it's something simple like SQLite, which has excellent PHP
> support. However, consider the many-users condition, MySQL is probably
> a much better choice.

It's still not clear for me, can saving data in SQLite simultaneously by a few users make SQLite database file corrupt?

Or maybe SQLite is not just a flat-file that is using SQL queries makes the difference?

Comment: If you are considering concurrency maybe SQLite is not the best option.

Comment: @TheImpaler But I can restrict such a concurrency in PHP, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you can also control it at the SQLite level with [`BEGIN CONCURRENT`](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md). Still, concurrency is not SQLite's greatest feature. For low concurrency it can work, but for high levels of it it's better to go with a server-like database like MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite primarily targets single-user, single-process use cases. However, some concurrency is still [supported](https://sqlite.org/threadsafe.html). The level of resiliency depends on whether thread-safety features have been disabled during compilation. Another important consideration is journaling mode (for details, see discussion of the [atomic commit](https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html) feature and references therein), but, basically, the newer [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) is designed to improve concurrent access. For discussion on how SQLite database may get corrupted, see [this](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think SQLite is for local use.

For example on a user device data is stored and when the system is idle, the data is updated in a 'main' database.